# How to invoke command on storyboard completed in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a button, which should close the current window, and open another one. But I want to first fade out the window, before closing it. I have a storyboard created:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Window">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

And I have the button:

```
<Button Content="Log In" Height="50" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
        Style="{DynamicResource ButtonLoginStyle}" Template="{DynamicResource ButtonBaseControlTemplate1}" 
        Command="{Binding LogInCommand}">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.LostMouseCapture">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"></BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

Is there a way to do it in XAML? Or should I do it in code behind? I'm trying to follow the MVVM principle, so I guess sending storyboard reference as a parameter to command is out of question.

I also have additional question, do you guys use blend for visual studio to create UI in XAML? Or is it a better practise to write the code yourself?

Answer (score 0):

If you are following MVVM pattern, I would recommend you to write pure UI related (storyboard animation) events in codebehind and not to bring in viewmodel & model.

Model.cs - Core Business Logic

ViewModel.cs - Business Logic Manipulated for User view and Dataload

View.Xaml - UI Design and Data binding

View.Xaml.Cs - Load Datacontext and Pure UI related events (Eg: storyboard animations)

Refer this article: [Most people are doing MVVM all wrong. Are you?](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/most-people-are-doing-mvvm-all-wrong.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can write this kind of storyboard in xaml.
You need to create a storyboard that targets your windows, therefore you should give your window Name.
The DoubleAnimation need to handle your "Opacity" from 1 to 0, with duration as you like. The storyboard has a "completed" event there you can close your windows and so on.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="BeginButton">
   <BeginStoryboard Name="MyBeginStoryboard">
            <Storyboard >
              <DoubleAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetName="myWindow" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                Duration="0:0:5" From="1" To="0" />
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

to your other question, blend is very nice to work with to preview complex styling, but only after you expert it in writing xaml. In my own point of view - it is way better to write your own xaml, for better practice

Answer (score 0):

That's I encourage you to do to solve it.

Create a behaviour that has two dependency properties:

```
public class StoryboardReactionBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
{
public DependencyObject AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

public void Attach(DependencyObject associatedObject)
{
    AssociatedObject = associatedObject;
    (AssociatedObject as UIElement).Tapped += StoryboardReactionBehavior_Tapped;
}

private void StoryboardReactionBehavior_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{

}

public void Detach()
{
    (AssociatedObject as UIElement).Tapped -= StoryboardReactionBehavior_Tapped;
}
```

}

and the two properties

```
public Storyboard Storyboard
    {
        get { return (Storyboard)GetValue(StoryboardProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StoryboardProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StoryboardProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Storyboard", typeof(Storyboard), typeof(StoryboardReactionBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, StoryboardChanged));

    private static void StoryboardChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var behavior = d as StoryboardReactionBehavior;
        if(behavior.Storyboard !=null)
        {
            behavior.Storyboard.Completed += (s, be) =>
            {
                if (behavior.Command != null)
                {
                    behavior.Command.Execute(null);
                }
            };
        }
    }
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(StoryboardReactionBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

And finally let's invoke when the reation happen:

```
private void StoryboardReactionBehavior_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Storyboard != null)
        {
            Storyboard.Begin();
        }
        else if(Command != null)
        { 
          Command.Execute(null);
        }

    }
```

I think is the most elegant solution and attachable everywhere.

Comment: Some XAML code that shows how to use this would be great! I really have no idea how to use this.